# can't reference field in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

Im writing a fairly simple python app using the pymongo driver.  when I try to access one of my fields like this:

```
return video_files_data[u'cloud_data']
```

but i get this error:

```
return video_files_data[u'cloud_data']
keyError: '\ufeffcloud_data'
```

when i remove the u' and put in double quotes, then i get

```
keyError: " cloud_data"
```

What stupid mistake am i making here?  It can't possibly this hard.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac0529b47949e0a1d04a523"),
    "file_id" : "NZwKy9PZy8M",
    "cloud_data" : {
        ...
    }
}
```

if i do `print(video_files_data.keys())` i get

```
dict_keys(['_id', 'file_id', 'cloud_data'])
```

but this works perfectly fine

```
for (key, values) in video_files_data.items():
    if key == "cloud_data":
        return values
```

Comment: Can you please post the value of `video_files_data` when the `KeyError` is raised?
Also, is there supposed to be a leading space in `" cloud_data"`?

Comment: i put the dump right out of mongo above.

Comment: Did you see the second question in my comment? I'm referring to the part of your question that looks exactly like this: `keyError: " cloud_data"`

Comment: yea, i saw it, i figured you would notice from the data that i posted that no, there is no space in the key name.  not supposed to be there.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying. Can you please post the line of code that raises the exception as well as some surrounding lines for context? Thanks!

Comment: I assume the offending line is something like `return video_files_data['cloud_data']`, so the main thing that would be helpful is the context.